# Does the Second Postulate of Special Relativity hold for non-inertial reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, acceleration, inertial-frames

That is, does the invariance of the speed of light hold for accelerated observers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the speed of light vary in non-inertial frames?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33816/)

Comment: How many examples have you worked through?