# With respect to what the speed of light is measured?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

[image]

We know that the propagation of light does not involve the oscillations of particles instead Electric and Magnetic fields oscillate. The variation of E and B fields results in the propagation of light, it does not require any medium for its propagation.

**Question:**

- Since speed of sound is measured w.r.t some medium which is 330 m/s,
  what about speed of light? W.r.t what it is measured and calculated as
  2.98 x 10^8 m/s?

Comment: Acording to special relativity, all observers, whether stationary or moving, will measure same value of speed of light. Moreover this  *standard* value is for vaccum medium.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of light in vacuum is measured with respect to any inertial frame.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments, it doesn't really matter because the speed of light is constant<sup>1</sup>. In other words, every observer will measure the same value for $c$.

There is however a slight nuance to this which is that this only applies to *[inertial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference)* observers, i.e. moving at a constant velocity without acceleration. Non-inertial observers might measure velocities greater than $c$, for example.

**TL;DR:** every inertial observer

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the second postulate of [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity): "The speed of light in vacuum is the same for all observers, regardless of the motion of the light source or observer."

Comment: Is it correct to say that for a non-inertial observer, the apparent inconstancy of $c$ is a consequence of mis-defining distance? That is, I measure my current distance, acceleration, and relative velocity towards a mirror and I say, "light emitted towards the mirror reaches me in less of my own proper time than $s'(t_1)+s'(t_2)/c$ where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are in my proper time but $s'$ is measured in an inertial frame initially comoving with me... so the speed of light is greater than $c$" -  when I should have been measuring my own proper length if I was going to be using my proper time?

Comment: @gs I'm honestly not sure. Maybe post it as an actual question?

Comment: I found an in-depth answer to that question here. If anybody else is interested: TLDR, not as simple as what I said, but yes, it's a consequence of adopting mathematically convenient coordinate systems that define distance differently. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33816/does-the-speed-of-light-vary-in-non-inertial-frames

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think of this is that the speed of light is measured relative to *nothing*. This is because there is no way possible to distinguish between an inertial frame of reference which is at rest and one which is coasting at a constant velocity. That means that everyone, irrespective of their velocity, will measure the speed of light as the same, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light in vacuum is measured with respect to the measuring device, not only in an inertial frame.

Earlier there was a hypothesis of a medium for the electromagnetic waves, just as sound waves are transported by air. This medium was called *aether*. But nowadays this hypothesis has been discarded and the waves are thought to not be waves of a medium.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether

Also, nowadays the length unit *meter* has been defined from the time unit *second* in such way that the speed of light in vacuum has been given the exact value $299\ 792\ 458\ \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$. This could be done because the speed of light in vacuum seems to be independent of the observers speed through universe.